# Download manager for file hosting sites like Megaupload, Mediafire

Tags: download-manager

Do you know of any download manager for file hosting sites like Megaupload/Mediafire that I can use so that after one file has been downloaded the other will continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/)

Comment: Isn't it possible to just input all the captcha. Because the default will prompt for the captcha everytime a download is finished

Comment: I have never had to type in a MU or MF CAPTCHA.

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Mipony](http://www.mipony.net/) for quite some time and I'm very satisfied. I had problems with JDownloader and switched to Mipony.

> Mipony is a free download manager specially designed to automate the
>   downloading of files of free host sites such as Rapidshare,
>   Megaupload, Hotfile and many others.