# Download manager like FlashGet

Tags: windows-7, windows, download-manager

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Download manager to replace GetRight?](https://superuser.com/questions/11874/download-manager-to-replace-getright)
>   [Download manager for file hosting sites like Megaupload, Mediafire](https://superuser.com/questions/131514/download-manager-for-file-hosting-sites-like-megaupload-mediafire)

FlashGet has a `Save as Default` feature for saving logins and passwords for sites like rapidshare, filesonic etc. It does not work. I have to re-enter the login details every time I download a file.

Any ideas how to resolve it?

Or can you suggest an alternative 'free' download manager that has features similar to FlashGet and also saves passwords for such sites?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally use [JDownloader](http://jdownloader.org/).  It's free, open source, and cross-platform (done in Java).

It allows you to enter premium account information, and automatically download files from nearly all file sharing websites.  Furthermore, it has built-in capcha detection (but may ask for human intervention if the pattern is too difficult to decipher).

Comment: Built-in Captcha detection? That's worth paying for. Only if Web Browsers had that ability. Oh wait, why doesn't someone just develop a plugin (ActiveX or whatever) for IE that can do that?